# migrate to centos vs. add centos repository

Tags: centos, redhat, rhel6, repository

I have installed Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.2, and I don't want to buy its subscription, I want to use the centos's repository.

I found an article that teach me how to migrate to centos 6 from rhel 6, http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide, since I don't want a "migration", I just want to add the centos's repository to my rhel. How can I do?

I have searched many article, but surprised to find no good tutorial..

I am also want to know, if I buy the subscription, then what? Will Redhat offer you a repository address to add to /etc/yum.repos.d/ ?

Comment: The effect is exactly the same in the end.

Comment: which effect? Did you mean the "migration" and just "add repository" are exactly the same?

Comment: Did you read the migration instructions? All you're doing is removing some Red Hat-specific packages and adding the CentOS repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am also want to know, if I buy the subscription, then what? Will
>   Redhat offer you a repository address to add to /etc/yum.repos.d/ ?

No, you will be connected to RHN, and will be able to manage the subscription channels you have paid for. This is more than just a plain yum repo.

Comment: thanks! So I will be connected to RHN, and manage the subscription channels online? But the yum software still need to find the repos in /etc/yum.repos.d/, right?

Comment: No, Red Hat offers a yum plugin, which authenticates your system/subscription to the Red Hat Network and manages the downloading of rpm packages. There won't be any repo entries in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.